# Need help laying out a page with CSS

Tags: css, html, absolute

I've been driving myself mad trying to figure out this seemingly simple placement of a div using CSS. I have a webpage that contains a single image, defined by CSS as background-image. I want to overlay a div that contains a a clickable link, as illustrated here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39682698/Fraud-Fighter2.png

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 and Absolutely Positioned DIVs to try make this happen. but when the page renders the link is not centered. I'm fairly new to CSS so some guidance on the best way to place objects using CSS would be much appreciated. I've used AP DIVs before with success.. not sure why it's not working now. Here's the page:

http://us.aktive.me/maintenance/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ThreatMetrix Maintenance Page</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv1"><a href="http://threatmetrix.com/support">http://threatmetrix.com/support</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: #3fa9f5;
    background-image:url(fraud-fighter.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-position:top;
    font-size : 1.5em;
    font-family : Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a:link     { background-color: transparent; color:#f28a1a}
a:visited  { background-color: transparent; color:#f28a1a}
a:active   { background-color: transparent; position:relative}
a:hover    { background-color: transparent; color:#cb7518}
a.noformat { text-decoration: none; color: #121212}

#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 351px;
    height: 43px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 233px;
    top: 240px;
}
```

Thank you SO much in advance for your help.
-Dean

Comment: so i've decided to switch back to using <IMG> for the image instead of using the background (lower res screens aren't presented with a scroll bar if the image is background). now i'm having issues overlaying the DIV again. i've updated the site: 

HTML: us.aktive.me/maintenance 

CSS: us.aktive.me/maintenance/main.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, going too far with positioning, no need. How about

```
   #apDiv1 {
        margin-top: 240px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

and thats it, works for me, since the size of the image is fixed

Comment: Thanks os much OJay! That worked perfectly. the code was created by dreamweaver when you click-drag an absolute DIV. I'll use your method in future, much easier :)

Comment: yeah those WYSIWYG editors can get a bit carried away with positioning

Comment: so i've decided to switch back to using <IMG> for the image instead of using the background (lower res screens aren't presented with a scroll bar if the image is background). now i'm having issues overlaying the DIV again. i've updated the site: 

HTML:
http://us.aktive.me/maintenance/

CSS:
http://us.aktive.me/maintenance/main.css

Answer (score 0):

If you need the text centered in its div, try:

```
#apDiv1 {
    text-align: center;
    ...
}
```